# HTTP request is being blocked

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

I am working on multiple apps that communicate between each other. I am using Chrome and Firefox both to test my apps on. The problem seems to be persistent in both browsers.

**The problem:**
I am sending a PUT request from app nr.1 to the Express Node server that essentially sends an update to my mongo database server. Once updated app nr.2 will retrieve the updated value with a GET request. Websockets are being used to notify apps on changes.

The problem however is that the HTTP GET requests on the receiving app nr.2 is taking multiple seconds for it to complete (after a few of them have been done).

To explain the written lines above look at the screenshot below:
[image: screenshot]

the first few GET request take 3-5ms to complete, then the upcoming GET requests will take up to 95634ms to complete....

What could be the cause of this and how could this be fixed?

Comment: Does your infrastructure has any throttling? It look like server is busy in doing something different. Your query has lowest priority

Comment: Don't use heavy sync operation in nodejs, if you don't use workers

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without seeing your whole stack.

Sometimes a reverse-proxy that sits in front of you applications can cause issues like this

They could be trying to route to ipv6 instead of ipv4 especially if you are using localhost to point your GET requests. The fix is to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Also, a high keepalive timeout setting on a proxy can cause this

Good first places to look in a situation like this are

- Proxy logs
- Node logs
- Server logs (ie firewall or throttling)